# Enable tint color change animation when creating UIButton programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not using the Storyboard to create my UI so I've created my button like so

```
var randomButton: UIButton = {
    var button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Random", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .highlighted)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeController.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()
```

The issue is that when the user taps the button it doesn't have a nice transition/animation between the tint colors. The color of the text doesn't change to black unless the user holds the button.

The normal behavior, when you use the Storyboard, the blue tinted text changes to a light blue color slowly. Not abruptly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the animation you are referring to is part of the system type button.

Try this:

```
var button = UIButton(type: .system)
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!